# cmake, lost in the concept of global variables (and PARENT_SCOPE or add_subdirectory alternatives)

Tags: cmake, scope, dependencies, global-variables, cmake-scopes

I have a cmake project in which I have some modules and I'm using Find-*.cmake for including the shared modules in the application.
For not taking in account every module that I add, I have defined a kind of global `LIB` variables tor the linker:

```
# inside a Find-*.cmake or in the CMakeLists.txt of the modules:
set(LIB ${LIB} ...)
```

so in one of the final applications that uses some modules I can just do:

```
target_link_libraries(${APP_NAME} ${LIB})
```

Then, I'd like to have the compiled modules in the `/project_path/modules/foo/build` so that if a module is really big to compile it can be compiled once for all the application that use it. The way I'm achieving this is to load the CMakeLists.txt of the module from the Find-*.cmake in this way:

```
# Inside FindFoo.cmake, for loading /project_path/modules/foo/CMakeLists.txt
# and compile it in /project_path/modules/foo/build
add_subdirectory(${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/../modules/${PACKAGE_NAME} 
                 ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/../modules/${PACKAGE_NAME}/build
)
include_directories(${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/../modules/${PACKAGE_NAME}/include)
```

But it happened sometimes that some module require another modules so that the `add_subdirectory` creates new scopes and can correctly load `LIB` but cannot write it (when I use `set` it is in the deeper scope and not changes the upper scope). For bypass this I have to add **PARENT_SCOPE** in the `set`).. So I have tried to add it in some module that I think could be nested and hidden in some dependencies but compiling all the application I suddenly faced with:

```
CMake Warning (dev) at /path_to_repo/cmake/FindFooX.cmake:6 (set):
  Cannot set "LIB": current scope has no parent.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:14 (find_package)
This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.
```

I am afraid that this can change from app to app in respect to which module I need or in respect of the dependecies tree in the modules itself so I'm looking for a cleaner solution.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

All variables in CMake are local by default. While you can use the `PARENT_SCOPE` parameter to increase the scope of a local variable by one layer, that mostly makes sense for return values of [functions](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/function.html).

For find scripts on the other hand you usually want the behavior of a global variable: Once the find script is called by anyone, you want the results to be available everywhere. In particular, a second call to the same find script should just reuse the results of the first call.
In CMake this is achieved by storing variables to the cache. The various `find_*` calls already do this automatically, so you should prefer using those where applicable. For any additional custom variables, [`set`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/set.html) offers the capability to store to the cache as well:

```
set(MY_GLOBAL_VARIABLE "Some value" CACHE STRING "Description")
```

Note that local variables can hide cached variables of the same name in their scope.

Comment: sorry but i have not understand exactly how to use this cached global variables.. i have tried to replace all instances of `set(LIB ${LIB} ${PACKAGE_NAME})` with `set(LIB ${LIB} ${PACKAGE_NAME} CACHE STRING "package description")` but in the end if i `message("-- ${LIB}")` only the first package i have called is included inside ${LIB}..

Comment: @nkint Check out the documentation for `set` I linked above. CMake assumes that cached values usually won't get updated once they have been created, so you need an additional `FORCE` parameter when changing them afterwards.

Comment: so i replaced everywhere with `set(LIB ${LIB} ${PACKAGE_NAME} CACHE STRING "Description" FORCE)`, also tried with `INTERNAL` but doesn't work anyway: no errors but the lib added in the subpackage added with `add_subdirectories` are no more present in the upper scope

Comment: @nkint Check that `PACKAGE_NAME` is not empty. The `set` command you posted is definitely correct, so if the error persists, you should put together an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) and post a new question.

Answer (score 36):

You can 'simulate' GLOBAL variable behavior, by using properties with GLOBAL scope :

```
SET_PROPERTY(GLOBAL PROPERTY MyGlobalProperty "MyGlobalPropertyValue")
```

Then you can extract your global property by using

```
GET_PROPERTY(MyLocalVariable GLOBAL PROPERTY MyGlobalProperty)
```

Then, *MyLocalVariable* contains "MyGlobalPropertyValue".

Because PARENT_SCOPE extends variable definitions  to the only parent directory (and not to its parents), there are cases it's not enough, for example if you have a deep source tree...