# CMAKE : set only if is not a repetition

Tags: cmake

I'm using a [global variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19345930/cmake-lost-in-the-concept-of-global-variables-and-parent-scope-or-add-subdirec) in cmake using `CACHE STRING FORCE` trick..

I want this simple test case to work messaging in the end only "dudee" and not "dudeedudee:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.10)
set(DUDEE "dudee")
set(LIB ${DUDEE} CACHE STRING "Description" FORCE)
set(LIB ${LIB} ${DUDEE} CACHE STRING "Description" FORCE)
message(${LIB})
```

Little explanation: Ok, I know that it is not nice to use global variable but cmake is kind of hell but I cannot track down the scope so `PARENT` can not work and I have a nice working example in which I set dependencies between different cmake modules and application that I wrote with global variable and it works.

But.. sometimes it happens that some modules call each other and each one is adding the dependencies.. a simple example:

application XXX uses the modules VideoReader, BlobDetector, VideoViewer, BlobTracker. All of those modules import the OpenCV libs dependecies in this way:

set(LIB ${LIB} ${OpenCV_LIBS} CACHE STRING "Description" FORCE)

and in the end I have the opencv libs a lot of time repeated in the `${LIB}` variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the context of a list of libraries to be used in `target_link_libraries`, then duplicates shouldn't normally cause any real problems.

However, to remove the duplicates, you should be able to use [`list(REMOVE_DUPLICATES LIB)`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/git-master/command/list.html).

Comment: yes it causes no error but it's just for debug.. create more readable log