# What's the CMake syntax to set and use variables?

Tags: cmake

I'm asking this as a reminder to myself the next time I use CMake. It never sticks, and Google results aren't great.

What's the syntax to set and use variables in CMake?

Comment: [offical cmake set Documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/set.html)

Answer (score 446, accepted):

When writing CMake scripts there is a lot you need to know about the syntax and how to use variables in CMake.

#### The Syntax

Strings using `set()`:

- `set(MyString "Some Text")`
- `set(MyStringWithVar "Some other Text: ${MyString}")`
- `set(MyStringWithQuot "Some quote: \"${MyStringWithVar}\"")`

Or with `string()`:

- `string(APPEND MyStringWithContent " ${MyString}")`

Lists using `set()`:

- `set(MyList "a" "b" "c")`
- `set(MyList ${MyList} "d")`

Or better with `list()`:

- `list(APPEND MyList "a" "b" "c")`
- `list(APPEND MyList "d")`

Lists of File Names:

- `set(MySourcesList "File.name" "File with Space.name")`
- `list(APPEND MySourcesList "File.name" "File with Space.name")`
- `add_excutable(MyExeTarget ${MySourcesList})`

#### The Documentation

- [CMake/Language Syntax](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-language.7.html#syntax)
- [CMake: Variables Lists Strings](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/community/wikis/doc/cmake/VariablesListsStrings)
- [CMake: Useful Variables](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/community/wikis/doc/cmake/Useful-Variables)
- [CMake `set()` Command](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/set.html)
- [CMake `string()`Command](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/string.html)
- [CMake `list()` Command](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/list.html)
- [Cmake: Generator Expressions](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-generator-expressions.7.html)

#### The Scope or "What value does my variable have?"

First there are the "Normal Variables" and things you need to know about their scope:

- Normal variables are visible to the `CMakeLists.txt` they are set in and everything called from there (`add_subdirectory()`, `include()`, `macro()` and `function()`).
- The `add_subdirectory()` and `function()` commands are special, because they open-up their own scope.
- Meaning variables `set(...)` there are only visible there and they make a copy of all normal variables of the scope level they are called from (called parent scope).
- So if you are in a sub-directory or a function you can modify an already existing variable in the parent scope with `set(... PARENT_SCOPE)`
- You can make use of this e.g. in functions by passing the variable name as a function parameter. An example would be `function(xyz _resultVar)` is setting `set(${_resultVar} 1 PARENT_SCOPE)`
- On the other hand everything you set in `include()` or `macro()` scripts will modify variables directly in the scope of where they are called from.

Second there is the "Global Variables Cache". Things you need to know about the Cache:

- If no normal variable with the given name is defined in the current scope, CMake will look for a matching Cache entry.
- Cache values are stored in the `CMakeCache.txt` file in your binary output directory.
- The values in the Cache can be modified in [CMake's GUI](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-gui.1.html) application before they are generated. Therefore they - in comparison to normal variables - have a `type` and a `docstring`. I normally don't use the GUI so I use `set(... CACHE INTERNAL "")` to set my global and persistant values.

  *Please note that the `INTERNAL` cache variable type does imply `FORCE`*
- In a CMake script you can only change existing Cache entries if you use the `set(... CACHE ... FORCE)` syntax. This behavior is made use of e.g. by CMake itself, because it normally does not force Cache entries itself and therefore you can pre-define it with another value.
- You can use the command line to set entries in the Cache with the syntax `cmake -D var:type=value`, just `cmake -D var=value` or with `cmake -C CMakeInitialCache.cmake`.
- You can [unset](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/unset.html) entries in the Cache with `unset(... CACHE)`.

The Cache is global and you can set them virtually anywhere in your CMake scripts. But I would recommend you think twice about where to use Cache variables (they are global and they are persistant). I normally prefer the `set_property(GLOBAL PROPERTY ...)` and `set_property(GLOBAL APPEND PROPERTY ...)` syntax to define my own non-persistant global variables.

#### Variable Pitfalls and "How to debug variable changes?"

To avoid pitfalls you should know the following about variables:

- Local variables do hide cached variables if both have the same name
- The `find_...` commands - if successful - do write their results as cached variables "so that no call will search again"
- [Lists in CMake are just strings with semicolons delimiters](http://www.cmake.org/Bug/print_bug_page.php?bug_id=2770) and therefore the quotation-marks are important
- `set(MyVar a b c)` is `"a;b;c"` and `set(MyVar "a b c")` is `"a b c"`
- The recommendation is that you always use quotation marks with the one exception when you want to give a list as list
- Generally prefer the `list()` command for handling lists
- The whole scope issue described above. Especially it's recommended to use `functions()` instead of `macros()` because you don't want your local variables to show up in the parent scope.
- A lot of variables used by CMake are set with the `project()` and `enable_language()` calls. So it could get important to set some variables before those commands are used.
- Environment variables may differ from where CMake generated the make environment and when the the make files are put to use.
- A change in an environment variable does not re-trigger the generation process.
- Especially a generated IDE environment may differ from your command line, so it's recommended to transfer your environment variables into something that is cached.

Sometimes only debugging variables helps. The following may help you:

- Simply use old `printf` debugging style by using the `message()` command. There also some ready to use modules shipped with CMake itself: [CMakePrintHelpers.cmake](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/CMakePrintHelpers.html), [CMakePrintSystemInformation.cmake](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/CMakePrintSystemInformation.html)
- Look into `CMakeCache.txt` file in your binary output directory. This file is even generated if the actual generation of your make environment fails.
- Use [variable_watch()](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/variable_watch.html) to see where your variables are read/written/removed.
- Look into the directory properties [CACHE_VARIABLES](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_dir/VARIABLES.html) and [VARIABLES](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_dir/VARIABLES.html)
- Call `cmake --trace ...` to see the CMake's complete parsing process. That's sort of the last reserve, because it generates a lot of output.

#### Special Syntax

- Environment Variables
- You can can read `$ENV{...}` and write `set(ENV{...} ...)` environment variables
- Generator Expressions
- Generator expressions `$<...>` are only evaluated when CMake's generator writes the make environment (it comparison to normal variables that are replaced "in-place" by the parser)
- Very handy e.g. in compiler/linker command lines and in multi-configuration environments
- References
- With `${${...}}` you can give variable names in a variable and reference its content.
- Often used when giving a variable name as function/macro parameter.
- Constant Values (see [`if()`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/if.html) command)
- With `if(MyVariable)` you can directly check a variable for true/false (no need here for the enclosing `${...}`)
- True if the constant is `1`, `ON`, `YES`, `TRUE`, `Y`, or a non-zero number.
- False if the constant is `0`, `OFF`, `NO`, `FALSE`, `N`, `IGNORE`, `NOTFOUND`, the empty string, or ends in the suffix `-NOTFOUND`.
- This syntax is often use for something like `if(MSVC)`, but it can be confusing for someone who does not know this syntax shortcut.
- Recursive substitutions
- You can construct variable names using variables. After CMake has substituted the variables, it will check again if the result is a variable itself. This is very powerful feature used in CMake itself e.g. as sort of a template `set(CMAKE_${lang}_COMPILER ...)`
- But *be aware* this can give you a headache in `if()` commands. Here is an example where `CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID` is `"MSVC"` and `MSVC` is `"1"`:

  - `if("${CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID}" STREQUAL "MSVC")` is true, because it evaluates to `if("1" STREQUAL "1")`
  - `if(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID STREQUAL "MSVC")` is false, because it evaluates to `if("MSVC" STREQUAL "1")`
  - So the best solution here would be - see above - to directly check for `if(MSVC)`
- The good news is that this was fixed in CMake 3.1 with the introduction of [policy CMP0054](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/policy/CMP0054.html). I would recommend to always set `cmake_policy(SET CMP0054 NEW)` to "only interpret `if()` arguments as variables or keywords when unquoted."
- The [`option()`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/option.html) command
- Mainly just cached strings that only can be `ON` or `OFF` and they allow some special handling like e.g. [dependencies](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/CMakeDependentOption.html)
- But *be aware*, don't mistake the `option` with the `set` command. The value given to `option` is really only the "initial value" (transferred once to the cache during the first configuration step) and is afterwards meant to be changed by the user through [CMake's GUI](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-gui.1.html).

#### References

- [How is CMake used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26007566/how-is-cmake-used)
- [cmake, lost in the concept of global variables (and PARENT_SCOPE or add_subdirectory alternatives)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19345930/cmake-lost-in-the-concept-of-global-variables-and-parent-scope-or-add-subdirec)
- [Looping over a string list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24986392/looping-over-a-string-list)
- [How to store CMake build settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17588517/how-to-store-cmake-build-settings)
- [CMake compare to empty string with STREQUAL failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19982340/cmake-compare-to-empty-string-with-strequal-failed)
- [When should I quote CMake variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35847655/cmake-when-to-quote-variables)

Comment: When I use `if ("${MyString}" ...)` I'm seeing warnings: *`Policy CMP0054 is not set: Only interpret if() arguments as variables or keywords when unquoted`*. See, for example, [Build 367](https://ci.appveyor.com/project/noloader/cryptopp/build/1.0.367/job/yp3lip31cotc6o1e). Any ideas?

Comment: And unquoting `${MyString}` leads to a bunch of errors for *"if given arguments ..."* like [CMake error near if: “if given arguments” followed by parantheses, “NOT”, “EQUALS” and similar](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39707772/608639).

Comment: @jww The warning means that `MyString` does contain a variable name that will then again will be de-referenced. I believe that nobody really wants that `OLD` behavior. So from my point of view its totally safe and backward compatible to just set policy `CMP0054` to `NEW` (see the discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41695993/cmake-ignore-the-warnings-of-external-modules)).

Comment: @jww And the safest way to avoid those problems/warnings is to just do `if (MyString ...)` (if it your code giving the warning).

Comment: Thanks. We removed all occurrences of `${MyString}` and replaced it with `MyString` (or I believe we removed them all). Still no joy: [Build 372](https://ci.appveyor.com/project/noloader/cryptopp/build/1.0.372/job/39oyux41cg60739f). The crap is not even coming from our code. It appears to be coming from CMake. Line 283 is `if (CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID STREQUAL "MSVC")`.

Comment: @jww Just do `if (MSVC)`, that works for all CMake versions. The [`MSVC`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/MSVC.html) check is exactly the example I used to explain the de-referencing problems with variables above.

Comment: @Florian Why is "MSVC" a "1"? What if I want to check if a string is a "MSVC"? What if I don't know that MSVC is a variable? Is there any way to disable it and to just do what should be the proper way: "${MSVC}".

Comment: "Local variables do hide cached variables if both have the same name" -- this is not quite true. Until CMake 3.21 (still unreleased), the `set(... CACHE)` command (even without `FORCE`) will **delete** a normal variable of the same name if either (1) the name did not exist in the cache or (2) the name existed in the cache, but did not have a type (such as if set via `-Dvar=val` at the command line). This will be [CMP0126](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/git-master/policy/CMP0126.html)

Comment: Also until CMake 3.21, `foreach(x ...)` command would overwrite `x` and leave it defined, but empty, after the loop. With [CMP0124](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/git-master/policy/CMP0124.html) it restricts `x` to a local scope.

Comment: How do I set these variables on the command line when running CMake?

Comment: Nice and informative. By the way, could you suggest some readings on `makefiles` and `cmake` for a c++ beginner?

Answer (score 31):

Here are a couple basic examples to get started quick and dirty.

### One item variable

Set variable:

```
SET(INSTALL_ETC_DIR "etc")
```

Use variable:

```
SET(INSTALL_ETC_CROND_DIR "${INSTALL_ETC_DIR}/cron.d")
```

### Multi-item variable (ie. list)

Set variable:

```
SET(PROGRAM_SRCS
        program.c
        program_utils.c
        a_lib.c
        b_lib.c
        config.c
        )
```

Use variable:

```
add_executable(program "${PROGRAM_SRCS}")
```

[CMake docs on variables](http://www.cmake.org/Wiki/CMake/Language_Syntax#CMake_variables)

Answer (score 6):

`$ENV{FOO}` for usage, where `FOO` is being picked up from the environment variable. otherwise use as `${FOO}`, where `FOO` is some other variable. For setting, `SET(FOO "foo")` would be used in CMake.