# Declare an empty list, and update it in functions

Tags: cmake

Let's say we have CMake projet like following:

```
proj_main
├── proj_sub_0
├── ...
└── proj_sub_n
```

Each sub-project may have zero or more than one targets. Number of sub-projects may change in situations.

For some reasons, we have to get a list of sub project targets for future use. It's reasonable to setup a list in *proj_main* and let let each sub-project to append targets into it.

Then here comes the question:

- Is it to declare an empty list in CMake?
- How?

**UPDATE**

As in comments heros mentioned that `set(name)` could define an empty list, previous questions got resolved.

But, here comes more.

Let's say we defined a list `foo` and a fucntion `func` in *proj_main/CMakeLists.txt*:

```
...
set(foo_list)
function(func var)
  list(APPEND foo_list var)
endfunction()
...
```

In *proj_sub_i/CMakeLists.txt* (where *i* may be anyone from 0 to *n*):

```
...
func(bari)
...
```

My expectation is that `foo_list` could be updated by `func` called in *proj_sub_i*. But the trueth is `foo_list` will stays unchanged. And more, even I call `foo_list` in *proj_main*, I could not change `foo_list` at all.

The `func` calling in *proj_sub_i* could not effect the `foo_list`. Why? What's the correct way to update the `foo` here?

Comment: Empty variable means empty list: `set(LIST_A)`.

Comment: @Tsyvarev Thought the `<value>` is must for `set`.

Comment: How are you using the list? Can you please post the CMake code you are using, at least a minimal example? The syntax suggested by @Tsyvarev is valid CMake language.

Comment: For your updated question see that one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22487215/cmake-function-parameter-and-return. It explains how to update outer variable within a function call. Note, that `add_subdirectory` call itself creates a variable's scope. For propagate variable from the subdirectory to the parent one you need again to use `set()` with `PARENT_SCOPE`.

Comment: @Tsyvarev Tks, please post asummary as anwser. Notice if you call the function from a sub-directory, you have to call `set(the_list ${the_list} PARENT_SCOPE)` again after the call of the function. If you have more than one level of sub-tree, you have to call `set(the_list ${the_list} PARENT_SCOPE)` in each.

Comment: Despite you concrete questions, your main problem seems to be a creating a **global list**. This is the same problem as asked in [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35777442/cmake-global-variable-in-macro-scope), so I have marked your one as a duplicate. (Note, that "duplicate" by itself doesn't mean "bad"; another wording for the same problem could be useful for search).