# Cmake: Looking up a variable in a cmake file without polluting the container scope with that of the other file

Tags: scope, cmake

Lets say I have a file info.cmake which has:

```
set(a 1)
set(b 2)
set(c 3)
```

Now a project can load it via include :

```
include(../info.cmake)
```

to access the value associated to `a` but that would pollute the environment with values for `b` and `c`. Is there any way of reading only the value of `a` potentially thorugh `get_property()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Florian mentioned, you will have to resort to using a function with its own scope. Here is a more general version of what was suggested which can be given the path to the source file and the variable to be looked up:

```
function(lookup value)
    set(options
            ""
            )
    set(oneValueArgs
            SOURCE
            VARIABLE
            )
    set(multiValueArgs
            ""
            )
    cmake_parse_arguments(LOOKUP "${options}" "${oneValueArgs}" "${multiValueArgs}" ${ARGN})
    if(EXISTS "${LOOKUP_SOURCE}")
        include("${LOOKUP_SOURCE}")
        set(key     ${LOOKUP_VARIABLE})
        if(NOT ${key})
            message(SEND_WARNING "No value was set for ${LOOKUP_VARIABLE} in the source file: ${LOOKUP_SOURCE}")
        endif(${key})
        set(${value} ${${key}} PARENT_SCOPE)
    else()
        message(SEND_ERROR "The source file was not found at ${LOOKUP_SOURCE}")
    endif()
endfunction()
```

This is how you can use it:

```
lookup(val
        SOURCE       ../info.cmake
        VARIABLE     a)
message(SEND_ERROR ${val}) #Will Print 1
```

Comment: Just a suggestion: replacing `if(NOT ${key})` with `if(DEFINED ${key})` would not send a warning if the value is `0`, `OFF`, `NO`, `FALSE`, `N`, `IGNORE` or `NOTFOUND`.

Answer (score 1):

You could add a local variable scope with a wrapper [function](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.4/command/function.html)

```
function(my_info_wrapper_function)
    include(../info.cmake)
    set(a "${a}" PARENT_SCOPE)
endfunction()

my_info_wrapper_function()
```

But this would only encapsulate local variables. Your `CMakeLists.txt` file will still be "polluted" if `info.cmake` does e.g. change cached variables or add any targets.

**References**

- [What's the CMake syntax to set and use variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31037882/whats-the-cmake-syntax-to-set-and-use-variables)