# Why do I need FORCE to override a CMake option?

Tags: cmake

I want to override an option, which formely was set to OFF. I am using

```
SET(USE_OPTION ON CACHE BOOL "Override option" FORCE)
```

Just for my curiosity: Why do I need 'FORCE' (without it, the set() does not work)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [docs](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/set.html):

> If CACHE is present, then the  is put in the cache instead,
>   unless it is already in the cache

I assume the previous option was also `CACHE`.

> If FORCE is specified, the value of the cache variable is set, even
>   if the variable is already in the cache.

So, if you don't specify `FORCE` it doesn't get added to the cache as per above.

Answer (score 14):

Options are variables meant to be changeable by the user after the configuration step and before the actual build enviroment generation through tools like the [`cmake-gui`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-gui.1.html), [`ccmake`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/ccmake.1.html) or through the `-D` command line switch.

That's why they are cached in the first place. The choice the user has done has to be persisted. So

```
option(USE_OPTION "My option" ON)
```

is an equivalent to

```
set(USE_OPTION ON CACHE BOOL "My option")
```

So to change or force an "user definable value" / cached variable you have to `FORCE` it.

Or hide/overwrite it for the current variable scope with a non-cached variable:

```
set(USE_OPTION ON)
```

**Reference**

- [What's the CMake syntax to set and use variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31037882/whats-the-cmake-syntax-to-set-and-use-variables)