# Run a CMake superbuild once and only once

Tags: cmake

In a CMake superbuild it is desirable to run the dependency build and project build the first time and then never again (unless desired). The problem I'm having with `options` and `set` is that I haven't found a way to set an initial value and then override it.

### Top-Level CMakeLists.txt

```
if( NOT DEFINED USE_SUPERBUILD )
    set( USE_SUPERBUILD on CACHE BOOL "Set the superbuild to run once" )
else()
    set( USE_SUPERBUILD ${USE_SUPERBUILD} CACHE BOOL "Set the superbuild to run once" FORCE )
    message( "Forcing USE_SUPERBUILD AFTER: ${USE_SUPERBUILD}" )
endif()
```

### superbuild.cmake

```
ExternalProject_Add( my_proj
        DEPENDS ${MYPROJ_DEPENDENCIES}
        SOURCE_DIR ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}
        CMAKE_ARGS -DUSE_SUPERBUILD:BOOL=off ${EXTRA_CMAKE_ARGS}
        INSTALL_COMMAND ""
        BINARY_DIR ${INSTALL_DIR} )
```

### Running it

```
Forcing USE_SUPERBUILD AFTER: off
```

### CMakeCache.txt

```
//Set the superbuild to run once
USE_SUPERBUILD:BOOL=on
```

When the superbuild gets to the end, it calls this script with `USE_SUPERBUILD=off` and it should store this value. For some reason even though it is getting to the `else()` block and setting `off` but the `CMakeCache.txt` still contains `on`. So the problem here is clearly the `ExternalProject_add` not calling the build such that it uses the root of the `CMAKE_BINARY_DIR` when you started. Is there a way to make `ExternalProject_add` work the same as calling `cmake -DUSE_SUPERBUILD=off ../project_source_folder`?

Comment: Would it be acceptable to just have the dependency build create an empty file when it succeeded and then just do an `if(EXISTS that_file)` from within the suberbuild `CMakeLists`?

Comment: Wouldn't it a solution to just negate your variables meaning? If you check in your code for something like `if (NOT SKIP_SUPERBUILD)` it would handle both cases `off` and undefined. And at the end `set( SKIP_SUPERBUILD 1 CACHE BOOL "Set the skip superbuild to run once" FORCE)`.

Comment: @Florian you could just cache on the first call, the issue is that the CACHE call the second time NEVER updates even with FORCE. It stays on.

Comment: @CameronLowellPalmer Overwriting with `FORCE` does work every time.I use that a lot. There has to be another problem. Can you go more into detail what you mean with "it calls this script with `USE_SUPERBUILD=off`"? I think we need a [mcve] here to reproduce your problem.

Comment: And I suspect that it is ExternalProject_Add is the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Switch from ExternalProject_add

The working directory is wrong with `ExternalProject_add` can be replaced with `add_custom_target`.

```
add_custom_target( my_proj ALL
        DEPENDS ${MYPROJ_DEPENDENCIES}
        COMMAND cmake -DUSE_SUPERBUILD:BOOL=off ${EXTRA_CMAKE_ARGS} --build ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}
        WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}
        COMMENT "Starting build ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}" )
```

Answer (score 1):

*Turning my comment into an answer*

I would just negate your variables meaning. To run superbuild only once I would do:

**superbuild.cmake**

```perl
if (SKIP_SUPERBUILD) 
    return()
endif()

[...]

# superbuild run finished, don't run again
set(SKIP_SUPERBUILD ON CACHE BOOL "Set to skip superbuild")
```

**Reference**

- [Why do I need FORCE to override a CMake option?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39588836/why-do-i-need-force-to-override-a-cmake-option)