# Cmake doesn't recognize MSVC compiler

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, cmake, openvr

It's the first time I encounter this error.

I am trying to clone [openvr](https://github.com/ValveSoftware/openvr) and get the hello opengl sample running, following [their instructions](https://github.com/ValveSoftware/openvr/tree/master/samples):

```
cd samples
mkdir build
cd build
cmake .. -G "Visual Studio 14 2015 Win64" -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=C:/Qt/5.6/msvc2013_64/lib/cmake
```

I get:

```
$ cmake .. -G "Visual Studio 14 2015 Win64" -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=C:/Qt/5.6/msvc20                                                                       13_64/lib/cmake
-- The C compiler identification is MSVC 19.0.24215.1
-- The CXX compiler identification is MSVC 19.0.24215.1
-- Check for working C compiler using: Visual Studio 14 2015 Win64
-- Check for working C compiler using: Visual Studio 14 2015 Win64 -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler using: Visual Studio 14 2015 Win64
-- Check for working CXX compiler using: Visual Studio 14 2015 Win64 -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Compilation set for 64bits architectures.
CMake Warning at CMakeLists.txt:40 (message):
  SDL x64 runtime binaries not provided on Windows.


CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:98 (message):
  Unsupported compiler.


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "C:/Users/GBarbieri/Documents/Visual Studio 2015/Projects/openvr/sample                                                                       s/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
```

If I go to check line 98:

```
if(   (${CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID} MATCHES "GNU")
   OR (${CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID} MATCHES "Clang"))
  # Better to use the prebuilt GNU preprocessor define __GNUC__,
  # kept for legacy reason with the sample code.
  add_definitions(-DGNUC)

  set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS         "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11 -include ${SHARED_SRC_DIR}/compat.h")
  set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG   "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG} -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -g")
  set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE} -O2")

  # Handles x86 compilation support on x64 arch.
  if(${PLATFORM} MATCHES 32)
    set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS        "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -m32")
    set(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS "${CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS} -m32")
  endif()
elseif(${CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID} MATCHES "MSVC")
  set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS         "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} /Za")
  set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG   "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG} /w2 /DEBUG")
  set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE} /MP /INCREMENTAL:NO")
else()
  message(FATAL_ERROR "Unsupported compiler. ")    // line 98
endif()
```

It seems it couldn't match `"MSVC"`.. let me do a try, let me add before this snippet of code:

```
message("${CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID}")
if(${CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID} MATCHES "MSVC")
    message("match")
else()
    message("!match")
endif()
```

And then it returns:

```
MSVC
!match
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:104 (message):
  Unsupported compiler.
```

What?

Can you spot what is wrong, guys?

Comment: Shouldn't it be just: if(MSVC)  ?

Comment: Have you tried this?  if(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID MATCHES "MSVC")

Comment: That works.. I'll modify the `CMakeList.txt`

Comment: Do you have cmake  version > 3.1 ?

Comment: cmake version 3.3.2

Comment: However it worked, I am now dealing with the qt

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Ok, as I've tried in the comment, the right answer is to use:

```
if(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID MATCHES "MSVC")
```

instead of

```
if(${CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID} MATCHES "MSVC")
```

Comment: If you are interested in the details why the first works and the second is not working see [What's the CMake syntax to set and use variables?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31037882/whats-the-cmake-syntax-to-set-and-use-variables). The funny part is, I used exactly this `MSVC` example there to demonstrate the problem with variable naming resolution.