# CMake does not use CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER as proper default

Tags: cmake

Our project is often cross compiled, so we want to allow a different target C++ compiler which is different from the one that runs on the frontend node. The `CMakeLists.txt` contain the following:

```
OPTION(target_cxx "select target CXX Compiler for building libqphix-codegen.a" ${CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER})
OPTION(target_cxxflags "select target CXXFLAGS for building libqphix-codege.a" ${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS})
```

When I call that with `cmake ~/Projekte/qphix-codegen/ -Disa=avx -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=g++ -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS='-O3 -march=sandybridge'`, I would expect that `target_cxx` gets set to that `g++` and the flags accordingly. However, the value of `target_cxx` is `OFF`.

I need to specify `-Dtarget_cxx` in order to get some other value than `OFF`.

Is there something one can do differently such that those variables get a sensible default value? I have the impression that the default value is evaluated too early.

Comment: The `OPTION()` call needs to be after the `project()` call (which evaluates `CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER`). But I'm not sure what you are trying to accomplish here. This looks more like something you put in different [toolchain files](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-toolchains.7.html) that you ship with your project.

Comment: I have fixed this by using `set` instead of `option`. I realized that `option` is for boolean options only. Now it works just fine. The toolchain stuff looks interesting, I will take a look at that later.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know about the `ON`/`OFF` restriction to `option()` command's initial value parameter. I've updated my answer for ["What's the CMake syntax to set and use variables?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31037882/whats-the-cmake-syntax-to-set-and-use-variables) accordingly. Do you like to [self-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `option()` only works with boolean variables, it is just to let the user pass a number of flags. What is needed here is `set()`. There are two variants:

```
set(varname value)
```

and

```
set(varname [default] CACHE STRING helptext)
```

The former creates a variable that is inherited by all subdirectories, the latter creates a user servicable variable that has string type.